# Countdown Timer with Progressbar not show progress

Tags: android, progress-bar, countdowntimer

i made a countdown timer with progress bar
but progress bar not show in percent

like this 
[image]

in countdown i use 60000 milisecond (1 minute) but it now show in progressbar with setprogress

i make xml like this

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbartimer"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:min="0"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

in updatetimer i used timelefttxt just to see countdown work or not

```
    public void startstop() {
     if(timerunning){
         stoptimer();
     }else{
         startimer();
     }
    }

    public void startimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeleftinmilisecond,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeleftinmilisecond = millisUntilFinished;
                updatetimer();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(pretest.this,"jawaban kamu salah",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startnum++;
                Dialogsalah(pembahasan);
                tampiljawaban.add(new tampiljawaban(question,jawaban,"-"));
            }
        }.start();
        timerunning = true;
    }

    public void updatetimer() {
        int progres = (int) ( timeleftinmilisecond/timefull )*100;
        progressBar.setProgress(progres);

        int minute = (int) timeleftinmilisecond/60000;
        int second = (int) timeleftinmilisecond % 60000 / 1000;

        String timelefttxt;
        timelefttxt = "" + minute;
        timelefttxt += ":";
        if(second < 10) timelefttxt += "0";
        timelefttxt += second;

        timertv.setText(timelefttxt);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove the  `android:indeterminate="true"` from XML use progress bar like this without that attribute

```
  <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbartimer"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:min="0"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

And set progress in updateTimer() like this

```
 public void updatetimer() {
     double progress = (60000 - millisUntilFinished) / 1000; // I have hardcoded max timer value i.e 60000 milliseconds i.e 60s 
            progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);

    int minute = (int) timeleftinmilisecond/60000;
    int second = (int) timeleftinmilisecond % 60000 / 1000;

    String timelefttxt;
    timelefttxt = "" + minute;
    timelefttxt += ":";
    if(second < 10) timelefttxt += "0";
    timelefttxt += second;

    timertv.setText(timelefttxt);
}
```

> Note : You might need to set the `android:max` attribute to 60 if you are using
>   this code